# Load classes using spl_autoload_register

Tags: oop

I have a problem with loading classes in a "includes" folder. Tried on a few WP installations and always same result.

I've made a simple plugin to see if the problem is somewhere else but again, it fails for some unknown reason.

Plugin folder name **test**

**test.php**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: test
Plugin URI: test
Description: 
Version: 1.0
Author: test
Author URI: test
*/

class test_main {
    public function __construct() {
        include_once( 'includes/autoloader.php' );
    }   
}

new test_main();
```

Then inside the **includes** folder I have two files, one of them is autoloader and another water class which for this purpose should kill it if it is loaded.

**autoloader.php**

```
<?php
class autoloader {
    public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register( array( $this, 'auto_load_classes' ) );
    }

    public function auto_load_classes( $class_name ) {
        if ( is_readable( plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/' . $class_name . '.php' ) )
        {
            include_once( plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/' . $class_name . '.php' );
        }
    }
}

new autoloader();
```

**water.php**

```
<?php
class water {
    public function __construct() {
        die( 'water' );
    }
}

new water();
```

**water** class is never loaded, why?

```
echo $class_name;
```

in **autoloader.php** returns:
**wp_atom_server**
**WP_User_Search**

I went to check a few plugins to see if anyone is using this set up and the only one I could find is WooCommerce and they basically have the same set up as above but for me it fails. Anyone has any kind of an idea?

### Edit

Well this is embarrassing and shows that one should sleep more :)
`new water();` should be called outside of the loader as the loader should not instantiate the class. `new water();` should be called in this example case in **test.php** file after `new test_main();`. Works just fine then.

Comment: Can you echo out what the final path is before trying to include it?

Comment: Yes, I did echo the path and the path to the folder is correct. Tried and checked this on multiple installations, two different servers.

Comment: The path is: `/home/test_site/wp-content/plugins/test/includes/` which is correct.

Comment: I'm glad you figured that out. :-) When the question gives you a chance answer your own question and give it the checkmark so others can find this answer in the future who may have a similar issue.

Comment: @Shawn, yes, I just did that but I have to wait until tomorrow to mark is as solved. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, to answer my own stupidity.

`spl_autoload_register` is called when you instantiate a class.

Moving `new water();` from file **water.php** to file **test.php** solves the problem.

The test.php should then look like this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: test
Plugin URI: test
Description: 
Version: 1.0
Author: test
Author URI: test
*/

class test_main {
    public function __construct() {
        include_once( 'includes/autoloader.php' );
    }   
}

new test_main();

new water();
```